# Bad function object

Tags: scheme

I am trying to compare if  two lists have same elements in them without considering order.

element-of? is part of set function to check if the element belongs to set

```
`(define (element-of? x set)
  (cond ((null? set) #f)
        ((equal? x (car set)) #t)
        (else (element-of? x (cdr set)))))
`
```

this is my code to check if list "a" has same elements as list "b"

```
`(define (check-unit-match cmp-to cmp-with)
  (cond ((null? cmp-to) #t )
        (else (let ((cmp-val (element-of? (car cmp-to) cmp-with)))
                (and cmp-val (check-unit-match (cdr cmp-to) (cmp-with)))))))
`
```

I am getting bad function object: ((m 2) (sec 1))

when i pass following argument 
 (check-unit-match '((sec 1) (m 2)) '((m 2) (sec 1)))

Comment: You are not comparing if two lists have the same elements rather than if every element in the first argument is a member of the second. eg.  `(check-unit-match '(1 2 3) '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7)) ; ==> #t`

Answer (score 0):

Your final line contains `(cmp-with)`. That is a function application. But `cmp-with` is a list, not a function.